# How to see the result of sqlite database file in firefox plugin when the app is run on iPhone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I am using sqlite database in my app. When I run the application from simulator then I am able to see the result in firefox sqlite plugin in my .sqlite file. But when I run on real device then I am not able to see the result so can you tell me how can I see the result and from where I can get that sqlite file.

Comment: you just have to reload the or refresh the firefox sqlite manager

Answer (score 0):

Short and Simple answer is "**You Can't**"

When you run on Simulator the generated applicationa nd Document files can be accessed in Library so you can easily check the sqlite file But
When you run on real device the sqlite file is in the document directory inside the device. and [Apple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.) does not allow to access the directory from device directly.

Comment: This not true, go into Xcode and open the organizer. Select your device from the device list. Now select the app from which you want to get all the files from. You will get an list of all the files in the sendbox, which you are now able to export.

Comment: @rckoenes Is that the app getting access to the files or XCode? Can an app access those files, or does Apple prevent them?

Answer (score 0):

1)**Enable Application supports iTunes file sharing** when editing the *info.plist* file in Xcode

2)**Connect your device** to system then **open iTunes** then click **device**(such as iPad) then click **apps** in that you can see file sharing choose your **app** from that now you can see your sqlite file *download* that and *open using firefox*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode version 6.1 the devices list has moved out of the Organizer.  I was able to view the files for my app by:

1. Clicking Window->Devices and selecting my attached device on the left.
2. Highlight the application I wanted to view.
3. Click the settings gear icon below the list and select Download Container.
4. You are asked where you would like to save the container archive.
5. In Finder, left click the container archive and select view Show Package Contents.
6. Navigate to the file/folder you want to view.

Comment: Yes, it downloads you a package, and when u open it u find all the App Data